# Ignore tag from the tag overlay

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

Would be nice if you could add a tag to ignore list right from the overlay. So common use case is you hover to read about this tag, and you are sure you don't know much about it, so you would like to put it to ignore. Right now I have to go through a lengthy process of finding that TextBox, type the tag in and click OK. Sample implementation can be like this:

Existing links:

```
faq, info, top users.
```

Proposed links:

```
faq, info, top users, ignore.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by clicking the star beside the number of followers twice.

Normal:

[image: normal]

Favourite:

[image: favourite]

Ignored:

[image: ignored]

Comment: Good answer - just not very intuitive. I mean why would you click `star` to ignore the tag? Also regular double-click does not work. You have to do two single-clicks. I still hope to see some `ignore` link.

Comment: No, double-click wouldn't work. That's why I said "click twice", not "double-click". :)

Comment: Yeah, I am getting used to it now. And it's still much faster than the way I was doing it before. Thank you.